# How to fix React 15.5.3 PropTypes deprecated warning while using react-transition-group

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

guys! 
Did anybody got 
`"Warning: Accessing PropTypes via the main React package is deprecated. Use the prop-types package from npm instead."` 
while using React 15.5.3 `"react-transition-group/CSSTransitionGroup"` add-on.

It looks like this addon uses old PropTypes.
Do somebody know how to avoid this Warning for this add-on?

Comment: It has been deprecated . Hence you need to install it separately.

Comment: Looks like a compatibility bug, try to open issue here https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group

Comment: Here is the code:
`import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-transition-group/CSSTransitionGroup';`
`                <div>
                    <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
                        transitionAppear
                        transitionAppearTimeout = { 1000 }
                        transitionEnterTimeout = { 1300 }
                        transitionLeaveTimeout = { 1000 }
                        transitionName = 'page'>
                        { selectInfoDisplay() }
                    </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
                </div>`
Using latest React 15.5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug fixed automatically when I updated "react-transition-group" to latest version. It looks that the npm package now works on PropTypes from 'prop-types'.

Answer (score 1):

It has been deprecated After React version  15.5. Hence you need to install it separately.,
**Install: npm install prop-types**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Component extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.text}</div>;
  }
}

Component.propTypes = {
  text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};
```

**Edit**: You need to get updated package for add-on compatible with react latest updates. It the package is yet not updated, you can make changes to them ypurself.

Comment: Ved , I think the problem is not with his own code but with a package that OP is using and wants a solution to the same

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri It seems that, he updated the react-version. Than he need to make changes in his code to resolve compability issues.